# Apply a function of two arguments to a n by two matrix

Tags: r

I have written this function

```
tippett <- function(p1, p2) {
  t <- 1 - (1 - min(p1, p2))^2
  return(list(p.value=t))
}
```

and I would like to apply it in a matrix of generated numbers *horizontally*. For instance in this matrix: `z <- matrix(c(rbeta(5, 1, 5), rbeta(5, 1, 10)), ncol=2)`.

Unfortunately `apply` does not seem to work and using it in this fashion `s<-apply(z,1,tippett)`

generates this error

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : argument "p2" is missing, with no default
```

Could you please tell me how I could circumvent that? It is my hope to generalize this procedure to thousands of rows and I can't imagine doing it manually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could change your function...

```
tippett<-function(p){
t<-1-(1-min(p))^2
return(list(p.value=t))
}
```

Then your function call should work. (I have not tested this though...)

```
s<-apply(z,1,tippett)
```

Alternatively, if you cannot change this function, you could try something like...

```
s <- sapply(seq_along(nrow(z)), function(i) tippett(z[i,1], z[i,2]))
```

I think that should all work. Sorry, running some code currently and cannot verify/test it.

Comment: This does work, thank you. Is that generalizable to higher dimensions? For more than 2 row elements, I mean.

Comment: @JohnK The function tippett takes a vector. So, yeah, I guess if you had rows of 24973535 elements it would only take the first two and generate the result.

Comment: Say that I include a third column in the matrix or another ten, how could I modify this function to take the minimum of all these elements in each row?

Comment: Ha. Sorry. I didn't even look at what the function was doing. I have edited to get a better, more general application.

Comment: No need to use apply there: A vectorized solution is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in one line:

```
tippet2 = function(z) as.list(1-(1-do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(z)))^ncol(z))

tippet2(z)
```

- This is vectorized.
- This applies to your matrix or a matrix with more columns.

Comment: Okay thanks, I have also found that `tippett<-function(p){
t<-1-(1-min(p))^(length(p))
return(list(p.value=t))
}` applies to more rows.

Comment: The power is dependent of the matrix number of columns?

Comment: Isn't the number of row elements?

Comment: It's not clear in your question since you fixed it to 2 :) and it's up to you to decide the definition of the function ...

Comment: Yeah it should be the number of row elements, my bad for not clarifying. Thanks for the heads up.